# Jest spyOn not working for ES6 class methods?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have created a class with some methods and I want to mock the methods inside that class so I tried to use spyOn() but it is not working any idea what could be wrong? I am using myClass.prototype instead of myClass in spyOn() but still it does not work.

```
class myClass {

    constructor(){

    }

    _methodA () {

    }

    _methodB() {

    }

    main () {
        const res1 = _methodA();
        const res2 = _methodB();
    
    }

}
```

tests:

```
it('Testing' , () => {

// Some mock data passed below

    jest.spyOn(myClass.prototype, '_methodA').mockReturnValue(mockData1)
    jest.spyOn(myClass.prototype, '_methodB').mockReturnValue(mockData2)

    const obj = new myClass();
    obj.main();

    expect(myClass._methodA).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(myClass._methodB).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

});
```

Comment: Don't spy on the thing you're supposed to be testing. The system under test is the *class*, internal method usage is an implementation detail.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Sorry did not get your point can you please ellaborate?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Do you mean to say I should not test methods inside class?

Comment: I mean you shouldn't test that main uses other methods inside the same class, test the overall behaviour instead. It seems like methodA and methodB are effectively private, and private methods shouldn't be tested directly.

Comment: @jonrsharpe How to test private methods or we should not test private methods?

Comment: You test them *via the public methods*. If there are private methods that aren't invoked by calls to public methods, you can delete them entirely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can spy the **class instance** methods:

```
it("Testing", () => {
  // Some mock data passed below
  const obj = new myClass();

  const spyA = jest.spyOn(obj, "_methodA").mockReturnValue({});
  const spyB = jest.spyOn(obj, "_methodB").mockReturnValue({});

  obj.main();

  expect(spyA).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  expect(spyB).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

You can spy the **class** methods:

```
it("Testing", () => {
  // Some mock data passed below
  const spyA = jest.spyOn(myClass.prototype, "_methodA").mockReturnValue({});
  const spyB = jest.spyOn(myClass.prototype, "_methodB").mockReturnValue({});

  const obj = new myClass(); 
  obj.main();

  expect(spyA).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  expect(spyB).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

The [other](https://pastebin.com/ZUZTzBVc) case using Db data is possible too:

```
it("Testing", () => {
  const obj = new classA();
  obj.main();
  const spyA = jest.spyOn(DBClass.prototype, "getData").mockReturnValue({}); // DBClass could be a db class or a mock class
  expect(spyA).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

Comment: So you are spying after creating the instance instead of spying before creating instance

Comment: Yes, that is the idea, create the instance and spy _methodA and _methodB functions, check if they were called on instance.main()

Comment: Will your answer work in this case : https://pastebin.com/ZUZTzBVc I have method from DB and I have created mockDB with methods in that case will your solution work?

Comment: Hi, where are you creating this bd object?

Comment: I have one question actually DB method getData is called inside main function in that case will that work?